# How to save Pandas pie plot to a file?

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'sample1':['foo','bar','bar','qux'], 'score':[5,9,1,7]})
sum_df = df.groupby("sample1").sum()
pie = sum_df.plot(kind="pie", figsize=(6,6), legend = False, use_index=False, subplots=True, colormap="Pastel1")
```

Which makes the pie chart. What I want to do then is to save it to a file.
But why this fail?

```
fig = pie.get_figure()
fig.savefig("~/Desktop/myplot.pdf")
```

I get this error:

```
'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_figure'
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Well `pie` is a numpy array because the return type for [`DataFrame.plot()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) is a numpy array of `matplotlib.AxesSubplot` objects.

```
fig = pie[0].get_figure()
fig.savefig("~/Desktop/myplot.pdf")
```

Answer (score 1):

Claim: My solution is save the current plot which works here, but it's not a good way to do this. What @user3100115 posted is the right way to do this.

Using `matplotlib.pyplot.savefig` to save it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.savefig('pie')
```

You'll get a image named pie.png like this:

[image: pie plot]

Comment: @user3100115 That's obviously ``ndarray`` does not have ``get_figure`` function, I think what he really want is to save the image successfully, right?

Comment: NO he's trying to plot a `DataFrame` object using [`DataFrame.plot()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) and I've posted the right answer.