# How to save a plot in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This code.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.get_figure()
fig.savefig("myplot1.pdf")
```

Gives the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_figure'
```

How can I amend this?

Comment: Can you show how you imported plt

Comment: Maybe relevant to your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32219350/how-to-save-pandas-pie-plot-to-a-file

Comment: Easiest solution: do not call functions that do not exist.

Answer (score 2):

First of all check whether a function exists or not in a module or library then only proceed. Also please explain the question with relevant or example data.

You can save the figure in matplotlib.pyplot as shown.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(x=[0,1,2,3,4,5],y=[0,1,2,3,4,5])
plt.savefig('saved_figure') #figure will be saved as saved_figure.png
plt.savefig('saved_figure.pdf') #figure will be saved as saved_figure.pdf
```

[The Saved Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQXoS.png) will look like this and it will be saved in working directory.

[The Saved Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GENf.jpg) in pdf format.