# How to send a chart using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, email, charts

I want to send a report email with charts, without using plotly. How can I send chart created with Pandas by email? Here is my code so far:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'lab':eventID, 'val':counter})
ax = df.plot.bar(x='lab', y='val', rot=0)

email_body=ax

msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = recipient
msg['Subject'] = subject

msg.attach(MIMEText(email_body, 'html'))
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp3.mycompany.com')
server.ehlo()
server.sendmail(me, recipient, msg.as_string())
server.close()
```

What do I need to add to make it work?

Comment: Pandas `plot` is based on matplotlib, so it will definitely involve calling `savefig('foo.png')` and then attaching `foo.png` to your email

Comment: @JoshFriedlander Do you recommend use different library to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas plot is based on matplotlib, so it just involves calling `savefig('foo.png')` and then attaching `foo.png` to your email.

Step 1 (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32219547)):

```
fig = ax[0].get_figure()
fig.savefig("~/Desktop/foo.png")
```

Step 2 - quoting directly from the [manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html) for Python `email`:

```
for file in pngfiles:
    # Open the files in binary mode.  Let the MIMEImage class automatically
    # guess the specific image type.
    fp = open(file, 'rb')
    img = MIMEImage(fp.read())
    fp.close()
    msg.attach(img)
```

Should get you pretty much there.